# If dropdown option value is "day" submit can't work PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, submit

I want if a dropdown option is selected my dropdown can't work if you click submit.
So the other things on my dropdown filled in, can not be added to MySQL.

How do I do this? I tried several options what I found on the internet but it won't work.
So if the value day is selected it can't work
and if the value month is selected it can't work
and if the value year is selected it can't work.

All the other options can work!

This is my form:

```
<form action="e2admin.php" method="post">
            <div class="input-group">

             <select name="dag">
                    <option value="day">Dag</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="11">11</option>
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                    <option value="13">13</option>
                    <option value="14">14</option>
                    <option value="15">15</option>
                    <option value="16">16</option>
                    <option value="17">17</option>
                    <option value="18">18</option>
                    <option value="19">19</option>
                    <option value="20">20</option>
                    <option value="21">21</option>
                    <option value="22">22</option>
                    <option value="23">23</option>
                    <option value="24">24</option>
                    <option value="25">25</option>
                    <option value="26">26</option>
                    <option value="27">27</option>
                    <option value="28">28</option>
                    <option value="29">29</option>
                    <option value="30">30</option>
                    <option value="31">31</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="Month">
                    <option value="maand">Maand</option>
                    <option value="1">Januari</option>
                    <option value="2">Februari</option>
                    <option value="3">Maart</option>
                    <option value="4">April</option>
                    <option value="5">Mei</option>
                    <option value="6">Juni</option>
                    <option value="7">Juli</option>
                    <option value="8">Augustus</option>
                    <option value="9">September</option>
                    <option value="10">Oktober</option>
                    <option value="11">November</option>
                    <option value="12">December</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="year">
                    <option value="jaar">Jaar</option>
                    <option value="1">2014</option>
                    <option value="2">2015</option>
                    <option value="3">2016</option>
                    <option value="4">2017</option>
                    </select><br>
                <select name="thuisteam1">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <?php
                        mysql_data_seek($result, 0);

                        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                               echo '<option value="' . $row['Team'] . '">' . $row['Team'] . '</option>';
                            }
                        }
                     ?>

                </select>
                <input onKeyPress="return alpha(event)" style="width:20px; text-align:center;" type="text" maxlength="2" class="form-control" name="scorethuis1" placeholder="0" />
                -
                <input onKeyPress="return alpha(event)" style="width:20px; text-align:center;" type="text" maxlength="2" class="form-control" name="scoreuit1" placeholder="0" />
                <select name="uitteam1">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <?php
                        mysql_data_seek($result, 0);

                        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                               echo '<option value="' . $row['Team'] . '">' . $row['Team'] . '</option>';
                            }
                        }
                     ?>
                </select><br>
                <select  name="thuisteam2">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <?php
                        mysql_data_seek($result, 0);

                        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                               echo '<option value="' . $row['Team'] . '">' . $row['Team'] . '</option>';
                            }
                        }
                     ?>

                </select>
                <input onKeyPress="return alpha(event)" style="width:20px; text-align:center;" type="text" maxlength="2" class="form-control" name="scorethuis2" placeholder="0" />
                -
                <input onKeyPress="return alpha(event)" style="width:20px; text-align:center;" type="text" maxlength="2" class="form-control" name="scoreuit2" placeholder="0" />
                <select name="uitteam2">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <?php
                        mysql_data_seek($result, 0);

                        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                               echo '<option value="' . $row['Team'] . '">' . $row['Team'] . '</option>';
                            }
                        }
                     ?>
                </select><br>
                <select name="thuisteam3">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <?php
                        mysql_data_seek($result, 0);

                        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                               echo '<option value="' . $row['Team'] . '">' . $row['Team'] . '</option>';
                            }
                        }
                     ?>

                </select>
                <input onKeyPress="return alpha(event)" style="width:20px; text-align:center;" type="text" maxlength="2" class="form-control" name="scorethuis3" placeholder="0" />
                -
                <input onKeyPress="return alpha(event)" style="width:20px; text-align:center;" type="text" maxlength="2" class="form-control" name="scoreuit3" placeholder="0" />
                <select name="uitteam3">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <?php
                        mysql_data_seek($result, 0);

                        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                               echo '<option value="' . $row['Team'] . '">' . $row['Team'] . '</option>';
                            }
                        }
                     ?>
                </select><br>
                <select name="thuisteam4">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <?php
                        mysql_data_seek($result, 0);

                        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){

                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                               echo '<option value="' . $row['Team'] . '">' . $row['Team'] . '</option>';
                            }
                        }
                     ?>

                </select>
                <input onKeyPress="return alpha(event)" style="width:20px; text-align:center;" type="text" maxlength="2" class="form-control" name="scorethuis4" placeholder="0" />
                -
                <input onKeyPress="return alpha(event)" style="width:20px; text-align:center;" type="text" maxlength="2" class="form-control" name="scoreuit4" placeholder="0" />
                <select name="uitteam4">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <?php
                        mysql_data_seek($result, 0);

                        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                               echo '<option value="' . $row['Team'] . '">' . $row['Team'] . '</option>';
                            }
                        }
                     ?>
                </select><br>
                <select name="thuisteam5">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <?php
                        mysql_data_seek($result, 0);

                        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                               echo '<option value="' . $row['Team'] . '">' . $row['Team'] . '</option>';
                            }
                        }
                     ?>

                </select>
                <input onKeyPress="return alpha(event)" style="width:20px; text-align:center;" type="text" maxlength="2" class="form-control" name="scorethuis5" placeholder="0" />
                -
                <input onKeyPress="return alpha(event)" style="width:20px; text-align:center;" type="text" maxlength="2" class="form-control" name="scoreuit5" placeholder="0" />
                <select name="uitteam5">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <?php
                        mysql_data_seek($result, 0);

                        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                               echo '<option value="' . $row['Team'] . '">' . $row['Team'] . '</option>';
                            }
                        }
                     ?>
                </select><br>
                <select name="thuisteam6">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <?php
                        mysql_data_seek($result, 0);

                        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                               echo '<option value="' . $row['Team'] . '">' . $row['Team'] . '</option>';
                            }
                        }
                     ?>

                </select>
                <input onKeyPress="return alpha(event)" style="width:20px; text-align:center;" type="text" maxlength="2" class="form-control" name="scorethuis6" placeholder="0" />
                -
                <input onKeyPress="return alpha(event)" style="width:20px; text-align:center;" type="text" maxlength="2" class="form-control" name="scoreuit6" placeholder="0" />
                <select name="uitteam6">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <?php
                        mysql_data_seek($result, 0);

                        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                               echo '<option value="' . $row['Team'] . '">' . $row['Team'] . '</option>';
                            }
                        }
                     ?>
                </select><br>
                <input style="margin-left:330px;" type="submit" class="form-control" value="Toevoegen" />
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: You can use javascript to do this

Comment: please post your php code which you get these values

Comment: try my answer, it works as you desired

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<select name="dag" style="">
      <option disabled="" selected="">Dag</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <!-- ...and so on... -->
</select>
```

Even it might look like they are disabled , they are still shown but you can't select them. And that means, that the user is forced to select something.

The rest has to be in JS or you validate your form before you write it into the database.
Somethin like:

```
if(empty($_POST['month']) || empty($_POST['day'])){
     echo "ERROR AT DATE";
}else{
     //HANDLE POST REQUEST
}
```

An example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ye88R/

Comment: I don't want it to be disabled. it needs to be shown. But it can not stand on the option value"day" if you click submit than there needs to be an echo error. I tried your javascript but it is not working

Comment: take a look at the example. It validates bevor you submit

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the disabled with value="", it won't let you send.

```
    <form method="POST">
        <select required>
            <option disabled value="">Day</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: I don't want it to be disabled. it needs to be shown. But it can not stand on the option value"day" if you click submit than there needs to be an echo error

Answer (score 0):

try this
Use jquery like this

```
$("#check").click(function(e){
 if($("[name=dag]").val() == "day")
{
alert("day is selected");
return false;
}  
 else if($("[name=Month]").val() == "maand")
{
alert("maand is selected");
return false;
}
});
```

add this line in `<head>` of html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pX6tT/4/)